# Can plywood permanently retain moisture in an isolated spot?

Tags: subfloor, moisture, plywood, humidity

The subfloor on the main level of my townhouse has several very small isolated wet spots.  There is a crawl space underneath, and I thought high humidity in the crawl space was the culprit, but I no longer believe that to be the case, and it actually seems like these spots don't change in shape or size, leaving quite the mystery.

I'm located in Maryland.  Carpet was removed in anticipation of installing flooring.  When several small (just a few inches) wet spots were observed in the subfloor, I placed a remote hygrometer in the crawl space to observe the humidity, and I started investigating crawl space encapsulation.  (This was after ruling out the easy stuff, like a plumbing leak or condensation source.)  The humidity was 90% so I thought I had the cause identified.  Aside from the high humidity, the crawl space is pretty much clean and dry, so I opted to start with placement of a dehumidifier to confirm that lowering the humidity would resolve the wet spots above.  I purchased a proper dehumidifier intended for a crawl space, and installed it with a condensate pump to take the discharge out of the crawl space (into an existing sump in my adjoining basement).  Humidity was quickly brought down to under 50% and has been consistently around 45% for well over two weeks now, but the wet spots remain.

Next I thought moisture must be trapped at the underside of the subfloor, and if I removed the insulation (batts between the floor joists) I'd surely find moisture that hadn't aired out.  I pulled out insulation directly under more than one of these spots, and the underside of the subfloor is completely dry.  Using one particular spot as an example, it's about 4" in diameter; from the living space side, a moisture meter reads something like 60%, but immediately next to the spot it's 8%.  Directly underneath that spot, in the crawl space, there's nothing there - no plumbing, no wiring, no moisture, the wet spot is between floor joists, and the underside reads 5% to 8% on a moisture meter.

Honestly it seems like these spots haven't changed at all in weeks, or even months.  The carpet has been gone for a long time; I've just not been working on solving the problem until recently.  Even with a high speed fan left on one spot overnight, it appeared unchanged.  I did just think to draw a pencil outline to observe any change, but it's been at least two weeks since the humidity was lowered in the crawl space and about a week since I pulled out the insulation.

Comment: Something you probably do not want to consider if you 100 plus weather temps is more heat.  Low heat from heat lamps might help.

Comment: @crip659 the wet spots are in the living space with A/C, so I could certainly point a heat lamp at one of them and see what happens, but I'm so confused by why it's wet to begin with.  Do you think it could have been from crawl space humidity but it's just very slowly drying from the bottom up?  When I found no moisture on the underside after pulling the insulation, I started questioning whether that was the root cause to begin with.

Comment: It is odd to be just in spots and seem like top down.  Any pets(or kids)?  Any heat source should be kept 12 inches or more away, you want warm not cooking.

Comment: Thanks for the followup @crip659 and no this isn't pets or kids (and I have neither), these are small, mysterious, seemingly permanent wet spots as described in my original question.  I'm trying to determine the root cause, so I don't put flooring down without knowing I've resolved the issue.  I'm hoping some other people weigh in with theories or additional avenues to investigate.

Comment: Plywood is made from three or more different types/plies of thin wood/wood products combined with glue, so different drying times.  Almost wish this was a very old house so I could mention the saying/meme.